# Bigtable from Dataproc: Dependency conflict even after shading the jars

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to run a Spark Application to write and read data to Cloud Bigtable from Dataproc.

Initially, I got this exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument`. Then came to know that there are some dependency issues from this Google Documentation - [Manage Java and Scala dependencies for Apache Spark][1].

Following the instructions, I changed my `build.sbt` file to shade the jars -

```
assembly / assemblyShadeRules := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "repackaged.com.google.common.@1").inAll,
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.protobuf.**" -> "repackaged.com.google.protobuf.@1").inAll,
  ShadeRule.rename("io.grpc.**" -> "repackaged.io.grpc.@1").inAll
)
```

Then got this error

```
repackaged.io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp, grpc-netty, or grpc-netty-shaded artifact
  at repackaged.io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider.provider(ManagedChannelProvider.java:45)
  at repackaged.io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:353)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.<init>(ChannelPool.java:107)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:85)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:237)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:231)
  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:201)
  at com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.EnhancedBigtableStub.create(EnhancedBigtableStub.java:175)
  at com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient.create(BigtableDataClient.java:165)
  at com.groupon.crm.BigtableClient$.getDataClient(BigtableClient.scala:59)
  ... 44 elided
```

Following that, I added the dependency of in my `build.sbt` file.

```
libraryDependencies += "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % "1.49.2"
```

Still, I am getting the same error.

Environment details
Dataproc details -

```
"software_config": {
      "image_version": "1.5-debian10",
      "properties": {
        "dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable": "true",
        "dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.enable": "true",
        "dataproc:jobs.file-backed-output.enable": "true",
        "dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.yarn.container.enable": "true",
        "capacity-scheduler:yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator" : "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator",
        "hive:hive.server2.materializedviews.cache.at.startup": "false",
        "spark:spark.jars":"XXXX"
      },
      "optional_components": ["ZEPPELIN","ANACONDA","JUPYTER"]
    }
```

Spark Job details -

```
val sparkVersion = "2.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies +=  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies +=  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-bigtable" % "2.23.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.google.auth" % "google-auth-library-oauth2-http" % "1.17.0"
libraryDependencies += "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % "1.49.2"
```

Comment: Can you check this [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/9152)?

Comment: @DominicT this won't work because I don't have direct access to make changes in the GRPCChannelBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue myself. I followed the following steps.

1. In the path `src/main/resources`, add `META-INF` directory and inside that folder, add `services` directory.
2. Inside `src/main/resources/META-INF/services` directory add 2 files, namely, `io.grpc.LoadBalancerProvider` and `io.grpc.NameResolverProvider`.
3. Add the following content to `io.grpc.LoadBalancerProvider` file `io.grpc.internal.PickFirstLoadBalancerProvider`.
4. Add the following content to `io.grpc.internal.NameResolverProvider` file `io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolverProvider`.
5. Finally make changes to your `build.sbt` as follows.

```
libraryDependencies += "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty-shaded" % "1.55.1"

assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.protobuf.**" -> "shade_proto.@1").inAll,
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "shade_googlecommon.@1").inAll
)

assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
  case path if path.contains("META-INF/services") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList("META-INF", _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```